# Pop_OS Grub can't find Windows

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, pop-os

I know this question was  answered before... But I'm so new that I don't even know how to do it :(
After installing Linux and giving it a try i found that I coudn't boot back to windows and I was stuck in Linux...which isn't really bad, but I still need windows.
I tried os-prober and boot-repair

***LSBLK command:***

```
AME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0   499M  0 part  
├─sda2          8:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─sda3          8:3    0 118.2G  0 part  /media/trollcraft1002/6EF006E2F006AFFF
├─sda4          8:4    0   565M  0 part  
└─sda5          8:5    0     1M  0 part  
sdb             8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0 461.8G  0 part  /
└─sdb2          8:18   0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap 253:0    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdc             8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdc1          8:33   0 927.3G  0 part
```

SDA3 is the Windows location
SDB is the Linux

```
OS: POP_OS 21.04
WINDOWS 10: 20H2
```

***sudo parted -l***

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG SSD 830 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   541MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      541MB   127GB  127GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      127GB   128GB  592MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 5      128GB   128GB  1049kB                                             bios_grub


Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72105 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      2097kB  496GB  496GB   primary  ext4
 2      496GB   500GB  4295MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1SB1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      16.8MB  996GB  996GB  ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap: 4294MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  4294MB  4294MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: can you boot into windows if you select the windows disk as the boot drive in BIOS?

Comment: When i choose to boot from ssd(where windows is installed) It opens grub with just Pop_os in it

Comment: ahh, right, I see the windows drive has a `bios_grub` partition - it looks like windows was using uefi boot and pop os has been installed using legacy bios boot - according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1652216/how-to-get-grub-working-dual-boot-windowslegacy-poposuefi) *most of the linux bootloaders installed for one firmware type cannot launch or chainload bootloaders of the other firmware type*

Comment: switching pop OS from bios to uefi is not simple, and fraught with danger, by the way

Comment: Anyway fixing it?

Comment: If i can install new windows and keep the old files then everything is fine. But I don't really know how to do it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Pop!_OS was installed with GRUB in legacy bios mode. It’s most common now to install it with systemd-boot in UEFI mode. When you do this you should just be able to hold F12 or Enter or something, depending on your bios/motherboard, and select Windows Boot Manager to boot to windows, or Pop!_OS  to boot to Pop!_OS. Note that this does not use grub or systemd-boot, it uses your BIOS to choose the boot software between Pop!_OS and Windows.